# remove "," from each line and put to arraylist in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

> Content of a file:

```
Afganistan,5,1,648,16,10,2,0,3,5,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,green,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,black,green
Albania,3,1,29,3,6,6,0,0,3,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,red,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,red,red
Algeria,4,1,2388,20,8,2,2,0,3,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,green,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,green,white
American-Samoa,6,3,0,0,1,1,0,0,5,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,blue,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,blue,red
Andorra,3,1,0,0,6,0,3,0,3,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,gold,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,blue,red
Angola,4,2,1247,7,10,5,0,2,3,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,red,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,red,black
Anguilla,1,4,0,0,1,1,0,1,3,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,white,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,white,blue
```

I need to remove **","** from the lines and put each line into an array separately.

The content of one line should be separate from other line using java

I used `ArrayList` but array includes commas.

Please help me remove **","** from each line.

> This is the code I have used so far:

```
String filePath = "/home/pavan/Desktop/flag.data";
try
{
    BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    String lineText = null;
    List<String> listLines = new ArrayList<String>();
    while ((lineText = lineReader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        String a = lineText.replaceAll(",", "");
        listLines.add(a);
    }
    lineReader.close();

    for (String line : listLines)
    {

       System.out.println(line);
    }

}catch(IOException ex){
    System.err.println(ex);
}
```

Comment: Post the code you have so tried.  This looks like CSV, so using a library to parse it would be best (eg [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/))

Comment: Look up how to read a file line by line. Then look up how to remove characters from a String. Then look up how to add to an ArrayList. Then Look up how to convert ArrayList to array.

Comment: Are you interested in reading it from a file, or simply split a long string?

Comment: reading it from file

Comment: String filePath = "/home/pavan/Desktop/flag.data";
  try {
   BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
   String lineText = null;
   List<String> listLines = new ArrayList<String>();
   while ((lineText = lineReader.readLine()) != null) {
    String a= lineText.replaceAll(",","");
   listLines.add(a);
   }
   lineReader.close();
   for (String line: listLines) {
   //System.out.println(listLines.get(5));
    System.out.println(line);
   }
  } catch (IOException ex) {
   System.err.println(ex);
  }

Comment: @PavanR Edit your code into the original question itself please.

Comment: The file may not have an extension of .csv, but it does contain  comma separated variables and @dsh 's suggestion is still valid.
I understand you want an array of strings, but with the comma's removed, how will you know where each number ends? How do you plan to process the strings once you have them in an array?

Answer (score 2):

```
   String [] newArray = yourString.split(",");
```

Comment: This is not correct. I'm not sure why this got 2 upvotes.